# ASP.NET Chart Control - Add Label to AxisY Crossing without removing automatic labels of major grid lines

Tags: asp.net, charts, asp.net-charts

I am using the [ASP.NET Chart Control](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/02/07/built-in-charting-controls-vs-2010-and-net-4-series.aspx) that Microsoft provides. I have a simple 2D chart with two series in it, one is positive and the other is negative. Here is what it looks like currently: [image: Picture of my chart]

I am guessing, because of my data range that the Y Axis at zero does not display by default. But if I add this line it does (as you can see in the above image):

```
AxisY.Crossing = 0;
```

AxisY is a reference to the Y Axis object. Is there a way to now label the axis without having to manually label all the major grid lines? If I do this it will label the Axis, but all the other dollar labels disappear:

```
Chart.ChartAreas[0].AxisY.CustomLabels.Add(new CustomLabel(0, 1, "0", 0, LabelMarkStyle.SideMark));
```

Here is my ASP.NET code:

```
 <asp:Chart ID="chartStudyResults" runat="server" AntiAliasing="All" 
        Height="650px" Width="690px">
        <Series>
        </Series>
        <ChartAreas>
            <asp:ChartArea Name="main" IsSameFontSizeForAllAxes="true">
                <AxisX Interval="1" IntervalAutoMode="VariableCount">                    
                    <MajorGrid Enabled="false" />                                
                </AxisX>                        
                <AxisY>
                    <MajorGrid Enabled="true" />
                </AxisY>
            </asp:ChartArea>
        </ChartAreas>
    </asp:Chart>
```

I am adding the series data in code. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Are you setting the AxisY intervals manually? If so you will need to adjust so zero is one of the major tickmarks or don't set the AxisY interval.

Comment: No, I am not setting the AxisY interval. I have such varying data that it would make for some really nasty graphing if I did that. I suppose that I could write an algorithm for doing as much though and maybe that would resolve my issue.